# where should I declare my variable session in my login.php, because I need this session to show user data

Tags: php

where should I declare my session, then how to call my variable session, I need it to show user data. Correct if my question is wrong

this is **login.php** for my condition

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["Username"]="$Username";
require_once '../include/DBOperations.php';
$response=array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  if(isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password'])){
$db=new DBOperations();

  if($db->login($_POST['Username'],$_POST['Password'])){
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['Auth'] = "Success";


  } else {
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['Auth'] = "Failed";
    $response['message']="invalid Username or Password";
  }
} else{
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['Auth'] = "Invalid";
    $response['message']="Required fields are missing";
  }
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

this is **DBOperations.php**

```
  function login($Username,$Password){
  $anotherConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sisro1");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pengguna WHERE Username='$Username' AND Password='$Password'";

  $result = mysqli_query($anotherConnection,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($row == 1){
    return true;
  } else {
    echo(mysqli_error($anotherConnection));
    return false;
  }

}
```

this is**DBConnect.php** for my connection

```
  function connect(){
      include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Constrants.php';
      //$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
      $dbName = "sisro1";
      $dbHost = "Localhost";
      $user = "root";
      $pass = "";
      $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $user, $pass);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Failed to connect with database".mysqli_connect_err();
        }
        return $this->con;
  }
```

Comment: You declare your session after you logged in and than you can recall your session with `$_SESSION['whatever your call it']`

Comment: _Small Note_ You dont need quotes around the variable in `$_SESSION["Username"]="$Username";` so can be `$_SESSION["Username"]=$Username;`

Answer (score 0):

you should start you session in the if condition of you login function

```
 if ($row == 1){
 $_SESSION["Username"]=$Username;
 return true;
 } else {
   echo(mysqli_error($anotherConnection));
   return false;
 }
```